# What can I use to record music coming from my computer?

Tags: windows-8, audio

I have some audio playing from my computer I'd like to record.

I don't want to use the microphone, as this would produce feedback.  I want to record straight from whatever the computer is spitting out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## For Windows Users:

Step 1: [Enable "Stereo Mix"](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39532/how-to-enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-to-record-audio/)

[image]

if you don't see it, you can try looping:

[image]

---

## For OS X users:

you can use [Soundflower](https://code.google.com/p/soundflower/):

> Soundflower is a free, open source MacOS system extension that allows applications to
>   pass audio to other applications. Soundflower is easy to use, it
>   simply presents itself as an audio device, allowing any audio
>   application to send and receive audio with no other support needed.

[Details](http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/25/record-system-audio-mac-os-x-soundflower/):

[image]

[image]

Step 2: Use a software like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) to record  "Stereo Mix", or your loop.

[image]

Comment: Windows' built-in tool [Sound Recorder](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/record-audio-with-sound-recorder) could also work.

Comment: Do you know how I could do this on OSX?

Comment: Using a looping (double-male ended audio cord) should work fine on any system with both a line in and a line out. Then use any sound recording software. For a software solution I don't know - not a Mac guy at all.

Comment: Added in the answer. I wonder whether we should indeed split into two different questions as it is getting crowded.

Comment: Some modern laptops use a combo TRRS cable for audio in an out. You might be able to do the loopback setup with a trrs male -> 2x trs female cable